# AngularJS $watch not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have a directive that should call a function whenever a service variable is changed.

The following code is inside the directive:

```
$rootScope.$watch('movesService.selectedMove', function() {
    console.log(movesService.selectedMove);
    if (movesService.selectedMove === "Punch") {
      vm.pushToFightLog('Select Target');
    }
    if (movesService.selectedMove === "Fury") {
      //Action
    }
    if (movesService.selectedMove === "Fortify") {
      //Action
    }
    if (movesService.selectedMove === "Parry") {
      //Action
    }
  }, true);
```

Service:

```
 angular
    .module('outerZone')
    .service('movesService', movesService);

  function movesService() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.selectedMove = "Punch";


  }
```

The thing is that when the $watch is called the first time it is able to read the variable and log it to the console, but even when the variable is changed after that, it does not fire the function.

I'm fairly confident that $rootScope is properly injected, but here is the code just to double check.

```
angular
    .module('outerZone')
    .directive('fightDisplay', fightDisplay);

  fightDisplay.$inject = ["alliesService", "enemiesService", "fightQueueService", "$timeout", "movesService", "$rootScope"];

  function fightDisplay(alliesService, enemiesService, fightQueueService, $timeout, movesService, $rootScope) {
```

Comment: can we have a working plunker ? that would help us to answer fast!

Comment: Essentially I'm wondering why this doesn't work https://plnkr.co/edit/YBrHJkblkZBmo4ozGusr?p=preview

Comment: Did the answer worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

With the plunker you have provided,I've made some changes in the watch function as below.

```
$scope.$watch('test', function() { //scope variable should be watched like this
    $scope.watchCount++
});//removed true for strict checking (===) as $scope.test is initalised as String 'Hello'
```

if we want a Strict checking then change `$scope.test =0` and

```
$scope.$watch('test', function() {
    $scope.watchCount++
  },true);
```

Here is the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NIvKP2knyLxarylKohTI?p=preview).To know more how $watch() works check this [blog](https://ngcoderscope.wordpress.com/2016/08/15/watch-digest-apply/)